# Laravel Eloquent hasMany returns null

Tags: wordpress, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Laravel 4 is giving me unexpected results on a new project. To try and help me better understand the results I tried what I thought would be a simple exercise and use a friends old WordPress blog on his web hosting.

Post model:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'wp_posts';

    public function meta()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Meta', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

Meta model

```
  class Meta extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'wp_postmeta';

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }
}
```

I have tried all of these variations with no avail...

TestController:

```
public function get_index()
{
//        $test = Post::with('Meta')->get();
//        $test = Post::with('Meta')->where('id', '=', '219')->first();
//        $test = Post::find(219)->Meta()->where('post_id', '=', '219')->first();
//        $test = Post::find($id)->Meta()->get();
//        $test = Meta::with('Post')->get();
    $id = 219;
    $test = Post::find($id)->meta;
    return $test; 
}
```

returned in the event listener:

```
string(47) "select * from `wp_posts` where `id` = ? limit 1" string(65) "select * from `wp_postmeta` where `wp_postmeta`.`post_id` is null" []
```

Please tell me I am just overlooking something really minor and stupid and I just need some sleep.

Comment: First of all, make sure that $id is not actually null by var_dumping it. Second, your relationship methods should be camelCased, not StudlyCased. I recommend using one-word names, so try renaming your Post::PostMeta method to just "meta". Once you do that you should be able to access the meta models via `Post::find($id)->meta`. Remember to update your question with these changes.

Comment: I updated to the recommended changed and also ran composer update but still have the same luck. I have tried get vs first with same results. Should I try a different relationship type?

Comment: What are the results of `$post = Post::find($id); var_dump($post->getKeyName()); var_dump($post->meta()->getParentKey());` ? Expected result should be the primary key column for wp_posts and the primary key of $post.

Comment: $post->getKeyName() is id but $post->meta()->getParentKey() produces an error "Call to undefined method". I did make sure that I set up the primary key for Meta as well
protected $primaryKey = 'meta_id';

Comment: Aha, you're on 4.0... OK, try `var_dump($post->meta()->getParent()->getKey())`.

Comment: I am... 4.1. And that one came back null.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44407/discussion-between-andreas-and-dasper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though is that while the SQL is case-insensitive, the array of attributes the model gets populated with is a PHP array where indexes are case-sensitive. The schema had the primary key as `ID`